# DataMapper fake property that's not stored in the DB

Tags: datamapper

Is it possible to set up something you could call a "fake property" in a DataMapper model? What I mean is, a property that isn't persisted, but that is still modifiable using create() or update(). Instead of persisting the data in the data store, a function would be called instead with the value.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that create() and update() do nothing more than `self.property = value`.

Answer (score 0):

Use `attr_accessor` in your model like this:

```
class Account
  include DataMapper::Resource
  attr_accessor :password
end
```

The method is explained here [what is attr_accessor in datamapper - ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9315648/what-is-attr-accessor-in-datamapper-ruby)